# Backbone call not working within React component function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a shortcut method within a React component, I added this helper function to the component:

```
    getLocalModel: function () {
        return this.props.localModel.get.apply(this, arguments);
    },
```

this.props.localModel is defined and it is Backbone model, but I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadResult' of undefined
```

I know the Backbone model is defined because I debugged and the error messsage appears. I believe there is simply something wrong with this call

```
this.props.localModel.get.apply(this, arguments);
```

anyone know what might be incorrect about it?

Comment: perhaps it's simply that I need to do: this.props.localModel.get.apply(localModel, arguments);

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, simple mistake, appears that the correct call to use was

```
    getLocalModel: function () {
        return this.props.localModel.get.apply(this.props.localModel, arguments);
    },
```